# Can't change the charset encoding

Tags: java, angular, tomcat, spring-boot

I currently have an Angular 4 app with a Spring Boot backend, both served on a tomcat 9 server.

No matter what I try, when I go to my application url, the content-type of the served html file is encoded in ISO-8859-1 (I want UTF-8).

I have added utf-8 in everything I could, from html files to server configuration, but it doesn't solve the issue (The data returned from the backend is encoded in utf-8, but not the html file).

Here is my current stack :

- Angular 4
- Spring Boot
- Tomcat 9
- Chrome 59 / Firefox 54

### In tomcat :

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>setCharacterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.SetCharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>encoding</param-name>
        <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <async-supported>true</async-supported>
</filter>
```

Added `URIEncoding="UTF-8" useBodyEncodingForURI="true"` in all the connectors I have.

### In spring :

Added content-type with utf-8 charset in the request headers.

### In HTML :

Added the meta : `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />`

If I forgot some informations, feel free to ask me.

Thanks.

Comment: Where are you seeing the character encoding of html? Is it in google chrome? If so which version?

Comment: I see it in chrome 59 and also in firefox 54. I haven't tried in other browsers.

Comment: it might be a problem with google chrome's automatic charset detection , which was introduced in chrome 55
https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=597488
Try  "wget " for your html from command line and see what is the charset of html that gets downloaded.
If it's browser's issue you can manually change charset by using some extensions.

Answer (score 1):

Actually I managed to make it work by changing the default filter from tomcat in web.xml by the spring's one :

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>encoding</param-name>
        <param-value>UTF-8</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </init-param>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>encodingFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```